# Is it correct to say "Rapunzel swung with her hair" or "Rapunzel swung by her hair"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

[image]

Normally we have these formulas:

1- **A person + verbs (hold, grab, swing, seize, etc) + a thing + with + a part of his body (his hand, leg, etc)**

For example, **I held the cup with my hand**

2- **A person + verbs (hold, grab, swing, seize, etc) + a thing + by + a part of the thing (its handle, etc)**

For example, **I held the cup by its handle**

Now, Is it correct to say "**Rapunzel swung with her hair**" or "**Rapunzel swung by her hair**"?

Comment: Assuming you have chosen Rapunzel because her hair activities are fairly common knowledge,  *Rapunzel swung her hair [down to her suitor]*.  If a giant lifted her into the air by her hair she would *swing by her hair.*  And if her shorn hair hung on a post like a fleece next to her hanged body, she would *swing [in the wind] with her hair*.

Comment: The actual picture here defies the laws of physics as well as biology. I'm sure no human being could grow hair that long - but regardless of that, Rapunzel's hair would immediately unravel and she'd fall to the ground, with just that one loose loop over the bough. Whatever - if we ignore those two impossibilities, it would also be possible to say she's swinging ***from*** her hair

Comment: @FumbleFingers [How this circus performer hangs by her hair](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=R8R6ESFMero) That picture may be unrealistic, but there are a number of aerialists who swing by their hair. There was even a musician who [did it for a music video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Aky-J-b9LcU).

Comment: @ColleenV: I never intended to imply that a human being couldn't hang by/from their hair - just that they couldn't have hair as long as shown above, *and* even if they did, it would need to be much more firmly tied in order to swing from it. But at least if your hair *was* that long, so you could hold it as shown, you wouldn't have to worry about the possibility of it pulling your scalp right off if you hadn't been sticking to your diet!

Comment: One important distinction: *swing* can be both transitive and intransitive ("I swing a pocketwatch back and forth" vs "I swing"). Your "cup" examples, and your formulas, include an object (cup). Your Rapunzel example doesn't. The formula can no longer be applied. There are still more connecting words possible: Tarzan typically swings *on* a vine. He swings *from* a tree. In Rapunzel's case, I think "using" is probably most applicable.